# ORM mapping to lucene

Tags: java, orm, pojo

I would like to create an ORM for lucene. Here is what i am trying to do .I have to make an POJO to map lucene Index.

Lets say i have a class

```
public class Users {

    public String username;
    public String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I need to map this class to a lucene index. I have used ORM lite for SQL but here the data source is a custom class which creates index, update etc. Is there any existing solution available or which is the best way to achieve it?.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in lucene, but I can answer you on a conceptual level.

The lucene index stores documents. A document consists of multiple fields. For each field you can instruct lucene to do different things, e.g. just store the field or to index it, which means, to make the field "searchable".

What you need to do:

*Data conversion*: Select a framework which converts your object into data you can store within lucene. You can use normal or improved serialization (e.g. kyro) and store the object as binary into lucene. You can also convert it to JSON or XML.

You add the serialized object value to the document and store it:

```
 document.add(new BinaryDocValuesField(name, new BytesRef(byteData)));
```

Now it is possible to store objects in lucence. However, you can only access them by iterating everything or by an unique document ID that lucene assigns. What you cannot do is the search for a user and return the password.

*Extract index fields*: To be able to search for a user or other contents of the object. You need to select the properties e.g. the username and add it as additional indexed field together with the binary data to each document.

A remark:

Lucene is designed as an indexing framework, not as a durable data storage. The typical use is that you use lucene for searching in data, that is stored at another place, e.g. in a traditional transactional database.

You can, of course, store the original data within lucene. But you there will be "challenges". For example a new lucene version may, or may be not, backwards compatible and read the index format of the old version. It will also be more likely that your index will be corrupt and unreadable if you have a power outage. In short: **The lucene index does not replace a robust and durable database storage technology**.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with Solr/Lucene before and I wouldn't try to write an ORM for Lucene because it's just not great for storing and manipulating data. You just get a single 'table', no real data types, no foreign keys, no unique constraints. You do get excellent search capabilities, but usually just a fraction of my data needs to be searchable. So it's simpler to store all the data in a place that is better suited for such a purpose, for example an RDBMS. Then you can use an existing ORM to manipulate your data, and configure Solr to read its index from that database by specifying appropriate queries in a configuration file. Hibernate Search can do similar things if you don't care about the Solr wrapper for Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this answers your question, but have you considered Spring Data?  I have used it with ElasticSearch and it was fairly powerful.  Can expose data via an interface and some minor annotations.  It also gives you a level of freedom to swap out the data layer with another technology.  It can perform the mapping for you although do a manual review afterwards as there can be some oddities.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago there was a project called [compass](http://www.compass-project.org/) that was exactly what you need.
[Here is](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/html/core-osem.html) how it could be used to map object to lucene's index. Unfortunately, today it is no longer under any development because its author founded amazing ElasticSearch.

Also, you could take a look at [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/), that should be pretty powerful too, according to [its samples](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#more-advanced-models).

Answer (score 1):

How about [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)? You can map very easily documents to java beans. For example, if your index has the following document:

```
<str name="username">john</str>
<str name="userpassword">johnpassword</str>
```

The following bean represents the document:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

public class Users {

    @Field
    public String username;

    @Field("userpassword")
    public String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here's how to query

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://solrUrl...");
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery("username:" + "john");
QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
List<Users> documentList = response.getBeans(Users.class);
```

Now you can iterate documentList and access each User returned by the query.

This also works the other way around..

```
Users user = new Users();
user.setUsername("Carl");
user.setPassword("passCarl");
solrServer.addBean(user);
```